# Scala on .Net HelloWorld

Tags: .net, scala

Following the README at https://github.com/magarciaEPFL/scaladotnet to create a Windows exe for a simple "Hello World" app:

```
package hello.world

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, World!")
  }
}
```

Built .exe with the command from the README:

```
scalacompiler.exe ^
-d C:\test\bin ^
-target:exe ^
-Ystruct-dispatch:no-cache ^
-Xassem-name HelloWorld.exe ^
-Xassem-extdirs C:\scala.net ^
-Xshow-class hello.world.Main ^
C:\test\src\HelloWorld.scala
```

While using Windows 7 Pro, 64bit, I receive this error when attempting a run:

> C:\test\bin>HelloWorld.exe
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'scalalib, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.    at Main(String[] args)

The Scala .Net compiler directory is directly in the path, yet it appears that the HelloWorld.exe is unable to find and load the scalalib.dll that is in that directory.  As per the comments below, copying the HelloWorld.exe directly into the C:\scala.net directory, and executing from there, works as expected.  But, placing the .exe into another directory, and the C:\scala.net dir as part of the PATH, does not.

What is wrong?

Comment: HelloWorld.exe and scalalib.dll are in the same folder?

Comment: No, HelloWorld.exe is in C:\test\bin\, and scalalib.dll is in C:\scala.net\ , with C:\scala.net being a part of the path.  I expected the .dll file to be found, being in a directory in the path.

Comment: Just tested it.  Copying the HelloWorld.exe to C:\scala.net dir, and running it from there, works.  I guess the question is confirmed; why is the scalalib.dll not found when the directory containing it is a part of the path?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(v=vs.71).aspx shows that the "Search Path Used by Windows to Locate a DLL" includes "The directories listed in the PATH environment variable."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET Framework does not follow Win32 in using the %PATH% environment variable for locating assemblies.

The short answer is: If it's not in the same folder, then it needs to be in the GAC, or it won't be found.

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153600/net-does-not-search-in-path-for-my-c-sharp-dll).

Comment: The minimum runtime DLL files I found necessary to copy into the the .exe dir for the HelloWorld.exe to work (already having a recent .NET runtime installed) are: IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll, IKVM.OpenJDK.Util.dll, IKVM.Runtime.dll, and scalalib.dll